# linear regression on time series - has to be stationary, even when finding relationship between X and y?

Tags: regression, time-series, stationarity, finance

## Question

- I am finding a relationship between the stock price and other features(predictors) such as the popularity among users or the price of ingredients.
- My goal is not to predict the future stock price.
- I am going to use linear regression between stock price (y) and features (X)

## Example

- Let's say I am curious to know the relationship between the stock price of Microsoft and "PC sales" and "Games sold". The example table is shown below.
- Do I need to calculate the percentage change of these values to make them more stationary values before applying a linear regression? So should I regress "Game sales growth" and "PC sales growth" on "stock return"?
- Or can I just regress the "Games sold" and "PC sales" on stock price?

[image]

Comment: You say that you are not looking to forecast the stock price. Then you must be looking for the causal effect of Games sold on Stock price and of PC sales on Stock price. Unless you have a completely and correctly specified DAG, which seems like an almost  impossible task in this case, the regression coefficients will not have causal interpretations. So, you are in essence predicting stock price, whether you like it or not because your coefficients will not have a causal interpretation.

Comment: @ColorStatistics What does the DAG mean?

Comment: Directed Acyclic Graph. Watch a bit of this terrific course to get a sense of what they are: https://www.edx.org/course/causal-diagrams-draw-your-assumptions-before-your

Comment: @ColorStatistics Sorry to say this but you seem to have wrong understanding of  regression. When people want to do a linear regression, they want to find correlation, not causality. So I cannot understand why you are using the term "causal effect" here. 

To tell you in more detail, performing a regression has two purposes. The first is forecasting and the second is interpreting the relationship. When the temperature rises, the more ice cream will be sold. We can find this relationship through regression.

Comment: However, it does not tell you which one cause which, even though the cause and result seem obvious to us, in this temperature and ice cream case. So I am not looking for any causal relationship here, but trying to just find a linear relationship between variables.

Comment: Most micro-economists, for example, spend their entire working day trying to tease out causal effects with regression analysis. When you have time watch the course at the link above, which is a window into how epidemiologists approach causal inference in observational data. You'll thank me later. Welcome to the world of causal inference. There is a whole new world out here!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to predict the actual prices and not how the change in X influences change in Y, you should not use the returns, but the absolute values.

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Should_I_use_prices_or_returns_for_a_correlation_analysis2) is a great discussion on this topic, especially the answer by Ricardo Barcelona.

Comment: The question in your link is about the correlation, but my question is about the slope coefficient in linear regression. Is the discussion thread, which you provided, still relevant to my question?

Comment: Yes, the question is about correlation, but if you read into the answer I have pointed to you should find the answer to your question as well. It actually uses regression as a way to back the reasoning.

Comment: Results using rental value growth and S&P500 returns show almost zero correlation. On the other hand, results using S&P500 price index and rental value growth show high correlation. How would you explain it? Is it only a matter of wrong methodology?

--> Do you have an answer to this question, which is from your link? I am experiencing the same thing but do not know why.

Comment: Part 1:Yes, it is a matter of methodology, of which the latter is wrong. In time series just because two series trend together does not mean that there is a relationship between them. That is why you should look at the correlation of returns or percentage changes to determine that. In other words you want to see how the series vary together to check for the relationship. If both series trend in any direction the trend will obscure their true relationship. Let's say that the changes do not follow any pattern.

Comment: Part 2: When one series goes up, the other sometimes goes down and sometimes up, There is no dependence. If they both trend in a similar manner over time there will be a high correlation, even though they are not related to each other at all.